# SOAP body and NameSpace using KSOAP2 in Android

Tags: android, ksoap

My soap requesting is generating like below,

```
<v:Body><submit xmlns="http://android.Test.com/" id="o0" c:root="1"><xmlString>Some String</xmlString></submit></v:Body>
```

But my requirement is like

```
<v:Body><n1:submit xmlns:n1="http://android.Test.com/" id="o0" c:root="1"><xmlString>Some String</xmlString></n1:submit></v:Body>
```

how to create the **xmlns:n1** to my method in envelop body using ksoap?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

add namespace in PropertyInfo.  It will auto manically set  instead of .

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    pi.setName("WorklistType"); 
    pi.setValue("PO_REQUISITION"); 
    request.addProperty(pi);
```